# How to calculate the velocity of an ionised gas when a field of 100 Tesla is applied?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, velocity, plasma-physics, gas

Say I have an ionised gas, oxygen/hydrogen and I am creating a magnetic field with a strength of 100 Tesla by inducing a voltage of 100 V/S in a magnetic material (the charge becoming 100, this gas is then being passed through a conductive pipe (maybe copper) with magnets acting as diodes to induce a one way gas flow, hypothetically this magnet gives the gas its velocity through the magnetic force applied to the ionised gas, how do I calculate the velocity?

Copper pipe is 5cm. How do I calculate the velocity and thus the time it takes for it to travel through this 5cm copper pipe when a magnetic field of 100Tesla/ a voltage of 100V/S is applied to the magnet?

Comment: A charge moving in a purely magnetic field does not change speed, only the direction.

Comment: Hi Milton, are you asking what the maximum speed would be if you discharged a ton of capacitors to give a changing electric potential of 100 V/s acting on some magnetic material?  Or on the ionized gas?

Comment: I am asking what the velocity of the ionised gas would be if it was in the presence of a field of 100 Tesla trying to move it through a conductive copper pipe which has a length of 5cm, what would the velocity of the gas be in cm/s?

Comment: I cant use the lorentz equation as i need to know the velocity of the gas to be able to understand what the force is, as F = QVB, i need to know the speed of the gas, S = D/T I know the distance that is 5cm but i need to know the speed of the gas to be able to know the time it takes to travel, trying to work on MagnetoHydroDynamics

Comment: @MiltonL.Rowlands - Without further information, no one can answer your question.  I was trying to provoke a little more information from you with my questions.  The magnetic field and the length of a copper pipe alone are not enough.  For instance, is your "100 V/S" supposed to be 100 volts per second?  If so, does it only act on the magnetic to generate the 100 T magnetic field?  (By the way, a time-varying electric field will generate a time-varying magnetic field, which can be used to infer some other things but there is incomplete info in the question currently.)

Comment: What are the questions you need answers from me in order to answer my question?

Comment: Yea i meant volts per second, which induces a field (B) with a strength of 100 Tesla, my question relates to S=D/T the distance it is travelling is 5cm, i want to know how long it would take for an ionised gas which is being moved in a direction by a field with a strength of 100 Tesla, so in even simpler terms... how long would it take for an ionised gas being moved by a field with a strength of 100T to travel through a pipe with a length of 5cm, S=D/T. What is the speed of the gas when a magnetic field of that strength is applied to it.